# PrimeNg <p-table> Multi Sort with MetaKey default sort (e.g. first two columns)

Tags: sorting, multiple-columns, default, primeng, p-table

I have a `<p-table>` table with `sortMode="multiple"`. I would like to specify two columns as the default sort when the page is first displayed. If I set sortMode="single" it works by specifying the sortField="year" [sortOrder]="-1" options (e.g. the header appears selected and the column sorted). What would be the equivalent for multiple columns?

Similar sample code (taken from https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/sort)

```
<h3>Multi Sort with MetaKey</h3>
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars2" sortMode="multiple">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
                {{col.header}}
                <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

```
export class TableSortDemo implements OnInit {

    cars1: Car[];

    cars2: Car[];

    cars3: Car[];

    cols: any[];

    constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars1 = cars);
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars2 = cars);
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars3 = cars);

        this.cols = [
            { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin' },
            { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
            { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
            { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
        ];
    }

    customSort(event: SortEvent) {
        event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {
            let value1 = data1[event.field];
            let value2 = data2[event.field];
            let result = null;

            if (value1 == null && value2 != null)
                result = -1;
            else if (value1 != null && value2 == null)
                result = 1;
            else if (value1 == null && value2 == null)
                result = 0;
            else if (typeof value1 === 'string' && typeof value2 === 'string')
                result = value1.localeCompare(value2);
            else
                result = (value1 < value2) ? -1 : (value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0;

            return (event.order * result);
        });
    }
}
```

I would like to set the default sort to be "year,brand"

So it appears like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question in case it helps others. You have to use the `multiSortMeta` property similar to this:

```
[multiSortMeta]="[{field: 'year', order: -1}, {field: 'brand', order: -1}]"
```

Comment: Can we set secondary sort predefined with customSort implemented?